# Displaying a bool array as a black and white screen in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, graphics, boolean, pixel

I don't really know how to ask this question because I don't know much about graphics, so there's probably jargon I'm not using.

I am currently using a 2D boolean array in C++ to store on/off states of pixels for a simple display, where position in the array corresponds to the position on the screen, and the value (true/false) represents whether the pixel is on (white) or off (black). I would like to know the best way to display this to the screen. I do not know any C++ graphics libraries, and though I'd be fine learning parts of one, it'd be nice if I didn't have to do that much reading. The project this is for is not meant to be heavy on graphics. It'd be nice if it could be as simple as something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
         window[windowTopX + i][windowTopY + j] = display[i][j];
```

Thank you very much!

Edit:
Oh, I completely forgot to mention this project is on Linux.

Comment: U can use SDL, SFML, HGE, OPENGL, DIRECTX

Comment: What is the resolution of the screen? If it is a small display, say 120x80, you could draw using ASCII, using a special character to clear the screen so that you're redrawing in place.

Comment: I tried using ASCII and it didn't look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with really simple 2D graphics, try give [Allegro](http://allegro.cc)
 a shot. It's extremely simple to learn, and has several functions that can make your life easier compared to SDL or DirectX. (It's cross-platorm, too!) The Allegro wiki has some resources that can help you as well. [The wiki page.](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_5_API_Tutorials)
Hope this helps!

Comment: I looked at that, but then I realized the GL I was already checking out before, CImg, would work. So I used that. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try using SetPixel, and the Windows GDI.

There's an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/61478/Drawing-Line-with-SetPixel) that would get you up and running. You can replace the SetPixel in that code with what you're trying to do.